# THREE.js reusing InstancedBufferGeometry with different instance count

Tags: three.js

I have InstancedBufferGeometry in THREE.js and I am able to use it to render same geometry lot of times. Now I want to split this into multiple sets of objects with different materials, all sharing same geometry (e.g. 100 green objects, 400 red, 600 blue, etc.).

Is it possible to reuse same InstancedBufferGeometry, or do I need multiple copies to have different instance count for each object? The only place I found instance count can be specified is InstancedBufferGeometry.maxInstancedCount, but I need different instance count for each material.

Note: number of materials is variable, as well as number of instances.
Using instanced attribute to change material is also out of question as each material uses lot of textures

Comment: I'm not sure if I entirely understand the question. But rather than have one instancedBufferGeometry, you should have three. I'm not entirely sure but i think as long as you have the instance attribute sized properly for each (400red, 600blue...), and they all use the same instance of BufferGeometry, they should be internally reusing them. WebGL wise, only the instanced attribute should be bound. If not three should be patched. Is this what you would expect?

Comment: @pailhead Thanks, that's what I ended up doing (attribute buffers are shared). Naming is still kind of confusing to me: `maxInstancedCount` is then actual number of instances, and maximum number of instances is determined by buffer size... It doesn't help that my use case can share instanced attribute buffer, so I was hoping for option to set actual number of instances on object ;). If you wish to post an answer I'll gladly accept it